# SQL Where Clause and Django Timezone

Tags: python, django, sqlite, datetime, timezone

I have noticed that when I return records from my SQL database using the following: `the_records = records.objects.filter(datetime__contains="2015-01-15")`, I get back the wrong records because the timezone is affecting the function call somehow - I know this because if I temporarily disable the timezone, the right records are returned. Can anyone offer assistance on what I should do to fix this problem (I still need to use the timezone).

Regards, Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that `datetime` is a Django `DateTime` field, and you're trying to get the results that have a value that matches the date '2015-01-15', ignoring the actual time.

In that case, you probably want to do a [`date`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#date) query, like: `Records.objects.filter(datetime__date=datetime.date(2015, 1, 15))`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to query your db with a timezone specific date, you can just create a datetime object that is aware of it's timezone.

Example:

```
# Get your timezone
from django.utils import timezone
my_timezone = timezone.get_current_timezone()


# Get create your timezone aware datetime object
from datetime import datetime
query_date = datetime(2015,01,15).replace(tzinfo=my_timezone)


# now you can run your query with a timezone specific datetime object
the_records = records.objects.filter(datetime=query_date)
```

This should solve your issue and get you the accurate results you need.
Please let me know if you still have any questions.

This [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/timezones/) has more info related to django timezones if you are interested in learning more.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, but this code does not give me the date, and when I extract the date part only and use that to filter my records, I still get the wrong records returned.